# Referer checking failed ( Referer is insecure while host is secure)

Tags: python, django

I am stuck at this error. I deployed my code on a production server and it is running on port 80. When I try to log in on the admin page. It gives me 403 error as shown in the image.

[image: CSRF verification failed,Request aborted.]

What could be possibly the reason? Is there some problem in my Django code or in nginx configuration?

setting.py file

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
SECRET_KEY = 'xxx'
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 ]

MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 ]

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
  ]


ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.urls'


WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
  'default': {
     'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
 }
 }

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
},
 ]

 STATIC_URL = '/static/'
 STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
```

nginx conf is:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.com;


access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

 error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
 location /static/ {
     alias /example/path/to/static/;
 }

location / {
    include /etc/nginx/sites-available/uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/path/to/project/yo.sock;
    uwsgi_param       UWSGI_SCHEME https;
    uwsgi_pass_header X_FORWARDED_PROTO;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto https;
   }
 }
```

How can I resolve this error ?

Comment: can you add SITE_ID = 1 in the settings.py and try it.

Comment: Nothing happened, still showing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are logging in using HTTP form url to HTTPS site

In that case you get following error

> ```
>  if request.is_secure():
>             # Ensure that our Referer is also secure.
>             if referer.scheme != 'https':
>                 return self._reject(request, REASON_INSECURE_REFERER)
> ```

You should change your login form url to https://

Comment: my site is on http, Nginx conf file above shows it very well. Is it necessary to use https while accessing Django admin page? When I try to log in on Django admin panel on production it shows me this error, not on the local host!

Comment: Why are you forwarding https header, proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto https;

Comment: Nope... I tried commenting it out but still gets the same error. There is something else wrong.

Comment: Did you comment out all 3 lines where you have https especially UWSGI_SCHEME also restarted ngnix